# sum on linked table in access changes each time query is run

Tags: ms-access-2007, foxpro, linked-tables

Our office still uses foxpro (dos version) for storing our process data. I need to develop lot of reports using the data available in foxpro. I linked the foxpro table to access database and wanted to develop some queries which can give me vairous reports.

Basically this data is production data having date of production, grade, product dimensions like thickness, width, length, weight, etc.

I tried the following query on this linked table

```
SELECT (smsslabs.dtp-day(smsslabs.dtp)+1) AS [Month], sum(smsslabs.wt) AS Weight, sum(IIf(smsslabs.dtofgrind<>0,1,0)) AS no_slabs_ground
FROM smsslabs
GROUP BY (smsslabs.dtp-day(smsslabs.dtp)+1);
```

Here, dtp is date of production, wt is weight of the product. Problem I face is every time I run this query, I get different results each time I run this query. When I convert the linked table to local table, I get consistent result and correct result. But I dont want to do the linking and converting to local table again and again before generating the report.

Please help me in getting consistent and correct result with linked table, so that I can make some more detailed queries to be used by non tech savy persons.

Comment: Well, is the data changing on an ongoing basis? If so then you will presumably get different results pulling from the live table all the time. The local table is a cached snapshot so will always return the same data.

Comment: Thanks Alan B for your interest. Data is changing on ongoing basis, but the frequency is too long. It can change once in about 6 hours. So change in source data is not the reason for different results.

Comment: I have found the solution. When I disable the option "Background" while linking the table, this problem disappeared. Now I get consistent result with same query. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. When I disable the option "Background" while linking the table, this problem disappeared. Now I get consistent result with same query. Thanks all.